# sorry for that kind of question but i must ask . How to create a table in SQLITE to ask me what to call a table

Tags: python, sqlite

E.g. After launching the program:

1. It is in interactive mode
   We are asked what name we want to create the database with;
2. After creating the database, the program asks us under what name to create the table in the database;
3. In the next step, the program asks us how many columns the table should have;
4. Enter the names of the mentioned number of columns and their types interactively;
5. Finally, create a database and a table with the columns indicated in it;

> 

```
import sqlite3
connection = sqlite3.connect(input("Enter the name for base: "))
cursor = connection.cursor()

table_name = input("Enter the name for table: ")
columns_name = []
columns_amount = int(input("Enter amount of coulms and name them: "))
for item in range(columns_amount):
    item = input("input theme mane of column: ")
    columns_name.append(item)


cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+table_name+"" )
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+ table_name +" ("+columns_name[0]+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,Name TEXT, "+columns_name[1]+" TEXT, "+columns_name[2]+" TEXT, "+columns_name[3]+" TEXT )") 

connection.commit()
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: Please revise post title: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Answer (score 0):

You can just create the sql string for table creation inside the loop like -

```
import sqlite3
connection = sqlite3.connect(input("Enter the name for database: "))
cursor = connection.cursor()

table_name = input("Enter the name for table: ")
sql_string = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {} (".format(table_name)
columns_amount = int(input("Enter amount of columns: "))

for i in range(columns_amount):
    column = input("input the name of column {}: ".format(i + 1))
    datatype = input("input the type of column: ")
    # You may want to check here whether column name and data type is valid or not
    sql_string += "{} {},".format(column, datatype)

# remove the last extra comma
sql_string = sql_string[:-1]
sql_string += ")"

print(sql_string)

cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {}".format(table_name))
# Finally create the table
cursor.execute(sql_string)

connection.commit()
```

Your code will not work because during table creation you are assuming that there are 3 columns which may not be true. So accessing those indices of `columns_name` might throw exception.